# Error after Connecting ios and android to firebase in flutter code in android-studio workspace

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, android-studio, flutter

**Im a flutter developer, i use code which runs perfectly fine on Android but doesnt work on iOS**

**Error iOS:**
Ld/Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Runner normal x86_64 (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    cd /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/ios
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -target x86_64-apple-ios8.0-simulator -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.2.sdk -L/Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCore -L/Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics -L/Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseInstallations -L/Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseInstanceID -L/Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleDataTransport -L/Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport -L/Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities -L/Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC -L/Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/firebase_analytics -L/Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb -L/Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCore -L/Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics -L/Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseInstallations -L/Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseInstanceID -L/Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleDataTransport -L/Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport -L/Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities -L/Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC -L/Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/firebase_analytics -L/Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb -L/Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/ios/Flutter -F/Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/ios/Pods/../Flutter -F/Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/ios/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks -F/Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/ios/Pods/GoogleAppMeasurement/Frameworks -F/Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/ios/Pods/../Flutter -F/Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/ios/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks -F/Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/ios/Pods/GoogleAppMeasurement/Frameworks -F/Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/ios/Flutter -filelist /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Runner.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Runner_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -lFirebaseCore -lFirebaseCoreDiagnostics -lFirebaseInstallations -lFirebaseInstanceID -lGoogleDataTransport -lGoogleDataTransportCCTSupport -lGoogleUtilities -lPromisesObjC -lc++ -lfirebase_analytics -lnanopb -lsqlite3 -lz -framework FIRAnalyticsConnector -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework Flutter -framework Foundation -framework GoogleAppMeasurement -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -ObjC -lFirebaseCore -lFirebaseCoreDiagnostics -lFirebaseInstallations -lFirebaseInstanceID -lGoogleDataTransport -lGoogleDataTransportCCTSupport -lGoogleUtilities -lPromisesObjC -lc++ -lfirebase_analytics -lnanopb -lsqlite3 -lz -framework FIRAnalyticsConnector -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework Flutter -framework Foundation -framework GoogleAppMeasurement -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Runner.app-Simulated.xcent -framework Flutter -framework App -lPods-Runner -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Runner_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Runner

duplicate symbol '_kFIRInstanceIDDomain' in:
    /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseInstanceID/libFirebaseInstanceID.a(NSError+FIRInstanceID 3.o)
    /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseInstanceID/libFirebaseInstanceID.a(NSError+FIRInstanceID.o)
duplicate symbol '_GULNSDataZlibRemainingBytesKey' in:
    /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities/libGoogleUtilities.a(GULNSData+zlib 3.o)
    /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities/libGoogleUtilities.a(GULNSData+zlib.o)
duplicate symbol '_GULNSDataZlibErrorKey' in:
    /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities/libGoogleUtilities.a(GULNSData+zlib 3.o)
    /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities/libGoogleUtilities.a(GULNSData+zlib.o)
duplicate symbol '_GULNSDataZlibErrorDomain' in:
    /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities/libGoogleUtilities.a(GULNSData+zlib 3.o)
    /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities/libGoogleUtilities.a(GULNSData+zlib.o)
duplicate symbol '_FBLPromiseRetryDefaultAttemptsCount' in:
    /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise+Retry 3.o)
    /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise+Retry.o)
duplicate symbol '_FBLPromiseRetryDefaultDelayInterval' in:
    /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise+Retry 3.o)
    /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise+Retry.o)
duplicate symbol '_FBLWaitForPromisesWithTimeout' in:
    /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise+Testing 3.o)
    /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise+Testing.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FBLPromise._pendingObjects' in:
    /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise 3.o)
    /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FBLPromise._observers' in:
    /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise 3.o)
    /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FBLPromise._error' in:
    /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise 3.o)
    /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FBLPromise._value' in:
    /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise 3.o)
    /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FBLPromise._state' in:
    /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise 3.o)
    /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBLPromise' in:
    /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise 3.o)
    /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FBLPromise' in:
    /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise 3.o)
    /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise.o)
ld: 14 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

**Another error for ios :**

** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
    Pods-Runner-hjgnynjimxqnmdfpzzwwspsaxybe
    duplicate symbol '_kFIRInstanceIDDomain' in:
        /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseInstanceID/libFirebaseInstanceID.a(NSError+FIRInstanceID 3.o)
        /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseInstanceID/libFirebaseInstanceID.a(NSError+FIRInstanceID.o)
    duplicate symbol '_GULNSDataZlibRemainingBytesKey' in:
        /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities/libGoogleUtilities.a(GULNSData+zlib 3.o)
        /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities/libGoogleUtilities.a(GULNSData+zlib.o)
    duplicate symbol '_GULNSDataZlibErrorKey' in:
        /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities/libGoogleUtilities.a(GULNSData+zlib 3.o)
        /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities/libGoogleUtilities.a(GULNSData+zlib.o)
    duplicate symbol '_GULNSDataZlibErrorDomain' in:
        /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities/libGoogleUtilities.a(GULNSData+zlib 3.o)
        /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities/libGoogleUtilities.a(GULNSData+zlib.o)
    duplicate symbol '_FBLPromiseRetryDefaultAttemptsCount' in:
        /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise+Retry 3.o)
        /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise+Retry.o)
    duplicate symbol '_FBLPromiseRetryDefaultDelayInterval' in:
        /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise+Retry 3.o)
        /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise+Retry.o)
    duplicate symbol '_FBLWaitForPromisesWithTimeout' in:
        /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise+Testing 3.o)
        /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise+Testing.o)
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FBLPromise._pendingObjects' in:
        /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise 3.o)
        /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise.o)
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FBLPromise._observers' in:
        /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise 3.o)
        /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise.o)
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FBLPromise._error' in:
        /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise 3.o)
        /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise.o)
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FBLPromise._value' in:
        /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise 3.o)
        /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise.o)
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FBLPromise._state' in:
        /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise 3.o)
        /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise.o)
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBLPromise' in:
        /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise 3.o)
        /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise.o)
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FBLPromise' in:
        /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise 3.o)
        /Users/nadavdaivdchibotero/Desktop/nadav/ata/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise.o)
    ld: 14 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    Pods-Runner-hjgnynjimxqnmdfpzzwwspsaxybe
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.

Comment: Looks like the important part of this "build error" is a lot of `duplicate symbol`s, you might want to change the title of this question or search on GitHub issues for the flutter Firebase library. https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues